# Regular expression that Must have at least one letter

Tags: c#, regex

I have a case where I am using a queue of regular expressions to filter out specific items in an Observer pattern. The filter will place the values in specific controls based on their values. However 1 of the controls pattern is that it can accept ANY ASCII Character. Let me list the filters in their order with the RegEx

```
Column         Rule                        Regex
Receiving     7 DIGITS                     @"^[1-9]([0-9]{6}$)"   --->Works
Count         2 digits, no leading 0       @"^[1-9]([0-9]{0,1})$" --->Works
Producer      any ASCII char.              @".*"                  --->too broad
              MUST contain a letter
```

Is there a regular expression that will accept any set of ASCII characters, but 1 of them MUST be a letter (upper or lower case)?
@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])$" -->Didn't work

examples that would need to go into expression

- 123 red
- red
- 123 red123
- red - 123

red

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match the whole rang of ASCII chars you may use

```
@"^(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])[\x00-\x7F]*$"
```

If only printable chars are allowed use

```
@"^(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])[ -~]*$"
```

Note the `(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])` positive lookahead is located right after `^`, that is, it is only triggered at the start of a string. It requires an ASCII letter after any 0 or more chars other than an ASCII letter.

Your `^(?=.*[A-Za-z])$` pattern did not work because you wanted to match an empty string (`^$`) that contains `(?=...)` at least one ASCII letter (`[A-Za-z]`) after any 0+ chars other than newline (`.*`).

Answer (score 0):

How about
`^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*$` ?

Between start and end of line, accept any number of any characters, then at least one a-z/A-Z character, then again any number of any characters.

Comment: This should work. Except, technically, to answer the OP's question you don't need the "+". That will match a run of at least one letter, but we only care that there is a single letter.

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more than just letters, it can't work. It won't work with a string that contains a newline (an ASCII char), either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oops, a typo (the A-z range).

Comment: Still, `.*` matches any Unicode code units from the BMP plane.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `[A-Za-z]+`.

It matches when there is at least one letter. You want something more specific?